# Is it true that $\lim \inf (x_n - y_n ) = \lim \inf (x_n ) + \lim \inf ( - y_n )$ if $(x_n)$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Consider the sequences $x_n$,$y_n\in\mathbb R$. We know that $x_n$ converges, but absolutely nothing is mentioned about $y_n$.
I saw in a proof the following claim and I don't get the reasoning  :
$$
\lim \inf (x_n  - y_n ) = \lim \inf (x_n ) + \lim \inf ( - y_n )
$$

Is this correct ?

Comment: Show the proof maybe?

Comment: Why the downvote ? There's no need for any additional context since I've provided my question in the most general sense, my only condition is that $x_n$ converges .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{n\ge k}x_n\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\inf_{n\ge k}x_n\tag{2}
$$
Note that the $\inf$ of a sum is no less than the sum of the $\inf$s
$$
\inf_{n\ge k}(x_n+y_n)=\overbrace{\inf_{\substack{m,n\ge k\\m=n}}(x_m+y_n)}^{\inf\text{ over a smaller set}}\ge\overbrace{\inf_{m,n\ge k}(x_m+y_n)}^{\inf\text{ over a larger set}}=\inf_{n\ge k}x_n+\inf_{n\ge k}y_n\tag{3}
$$
Since $y_n=(x_n+y_n)+(-x_n)$, we can apply $(3)$:
$$
\inf_{n\ge k}y_n\ge\inf_{n\ge k}(x_n+y_n)+\inf_{n\ge k}(-x_n)\tag{4}
$$
Since $\sup\limits_{n\ge k}x_n=-\inf\limits_{n\ge k}(-x_n)$, $(4)$ becomes
$$
\sup_{n\ge k}x_n+\inf_{n\ge k}y_n\ge\inf_{n\ge k}(x_n+y_n)\tag{5}
$$
Combine $(3)$ and $(5)$:
$$
\sup_{n\ge k}x_n+\inf_{n\ge k}y_n\ge\inf_{n\ge k}(x_n+y_n)\ge\inf_{n\ge k}x_n+\inf_{n\ge k}y_n\tag{6}
$$
Taking the limit of $(6)$ yields
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n+\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n\ge\liminf_{n\to\infty}(x_n+y_n)\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n+\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n\tag{7}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n+\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}(x_n+y_n)\tag{8}
$$
Now just substitute $y_n\mapsto-y_n$.

Comment: Sorry I haven't marked an answer in such a long time, I completely forgot about this question.My sincere apologies @robjohn and thank you very much for your detailed proof !

Comment: No problem. Voting is so unpredictable, I just answer questions as best as I can and the votes and acceptances are just happy occurrences sprinkled on later.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is correct, and it can be simplified as
$$
\liminf (x_n-y_n)=\lim x_n-\limsup y_n.
$$

Comment: but he says $x_n$ converges...

Comment: Yep, that's right.. @TroyWoo

Comment: I can't believe you accepted this. @Victor

Comment: @TroyWoo I didn't, probably just misclicked. I always thank anyone who provides me with insightful answers (obviously not the case here). Thanks for the nudge

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the definition of $\liminf$ as the smallest limit of a convergent subsequence.

Since $x_n$ converges, if a subsequence of $(-y_n)$ converges then so does the corresponding subsequence of $(x_n-y_n)$. Moreover the limit of every such subsequence of $(x_n-y_n)$ is just the limit of the corresponding subsequence of $(-y_n)$ shifted by an amount equal to the limit of $x_n$ (since each subsequence of $x_n$ has this limit).

Since the amount of this shift does not vary from subsequence to subsequence, the subsequence for which the limit of $(-y_n)$ is smallest will also be the subsequence for which the limit of $(x_n-y_n)$ is the smallest and so we have

$$\liminf(x_n-y_n) = \lim x_n + \liminf (-y_n)$$